# Thread using 100% CPU

Tags: multithreading, timer, cpu-usage

So my thread is calling this function and I guess that because of the endless loop I get 100% CPU usage.

I just want the thread to check if timeInSeconds > stoptimer (maybe if I can check for example every 10 seconds instead of the endless loop the problem with the CPU will be eliminated).

startTime gets reseted by the main program if certain event occurs, so basically the thread stops my main program if the event doesn't occur for some time.

```
void foo(){
    while(true){
    clock_t endTime = clock();
    clock_t clockTicksTaken = endTime - startTime;
    double timeInSeconds = clockTicksTaken / (double) CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

    if (timeInSeconds > stoptimer){
            cout << timeInSeconds << " seconds passed, closed due to timeout." << "\n";
            stop = 1;
            break;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You are right, you need to insert a sleep inside the loop, a 500 milliseconds sleep should be sufficient.

Comment: void foo() { cout << "test1"; while(true){ clock_t endTime = clock(); clock_t clockTicksTaken = endTime - startTime; double timeInSeconds = clockTicksTaken / (double) CLOCKS_PER_SEC; cout << "test2"; if (timeInSeconds > stoptimer) { cout << timeInSeconds << " seconds passed, closed due to timeout." << "\n"; stop = 1; break; } cout << "test3"; sleep(5); } } In this case it is not working, I don't get any of the print outs.